# Getting started: no phonegap template in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova, xcode4.3

I have installed Xcode from Apple Store and run the PhoneGap installer libs/ios from PhoneGap.
Now, when opening XCode I cannot see the Phonegap template in [image: Xcode]

What I should get is in the Image below. Any idea what I;m doing wrong? I'm very new to phoneGap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Phonegap 2.0? They removed this template in Phonegap 2.0. Now you need to use the command line to create a new app, but it's pretty easy and described [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS).

Comment: Yeah I'm using Phone Gap 2 Thanks for your hit